# What does "foreign platforms" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bourne-legacy

In *The Bourne Legacy (2012)*, In Washington D.C., Byer team are hunting for Dr. Shearing.
Earlier, Dr. Shearing was saved by Aaron Cross from CIA agents,
who was send to kill her. In strategic planning room, Zev Vendal
reporting to C-Team about the house location, where Dr. Shearing
earlier stationed:

> Zev Vendal: Maryland's not exactly a high-value U.S. target. There'll
> be plenty of weather imaging, but we're gonna have to swing a little
> wider to find something real-time that's enhanceable.
>
> C-Team: We're draining some **foreign platforms**. We need about an hour.

What does "foreign platforms" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It means using assets, satellites, cameras etc from non-CIA sources

Foreign does not necessarily mean overseas, it could be other US agency satellites, or, *possibly* non-US governmental equipment up to and including assets from other governments, agencies and corporations.